# How to Update Gridview Row without saving data to database

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a GridView I am using built in Edit method that comes along with GridView in ASP.NET Web Forms. I want to Edit/Update the row in such way that it should only be updated 
dynamically in row and should not update records in database. The updated content should be hard coded to row temporarily. Can Any one help me do this task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying to do this using Jquery to do this but Gridview render controls on server so I am unable to call or link any button or Text box.

Comment: make a button which doesn't cause the gridview to post back, and then you can use jquery to manipulate the grid contents.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a DataTable. Populate your DataTable with any data you want and bind it to your GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I only can give an answer no comment but my suggestion would be: Keep your data (GridView/Table) in a Session Variable and display this data until you wanna update.